# Not able to clone using dulwich python

Tags: git, python-2.7, gitlab, dulwich

I am trying clone a repository from a remote gitlab server using the python dulwich module. However I am getting  the following error :

```
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

There is no firewall blocking the connection because I am easily able to clone using ssh.

This is the code that I had used.

```
from dulwich import porcelain
porcelain.clone(url, path)
```

Comment: What is the url you are passing in, or what does it look like? The error suggests dulwich is not trying to use SSH but plain TCP.

Comment: @jelmer i have passed both http and ssh urls

Comment: What's the error you get when passing in a SSH URL?

Comment: @jelmer i am getting the same error..the url I used is this one :  porcelain.clone("git:git@10.66.87.176:infosys/admin-test.git", "mukul")

Comment: That's not a SSH URL, but a plain TCP URL. You probably want something like ssh://git@10.66.87.176/infosys/admin-test.git

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a plain TCP/IP URL, but expecting a connection to happen over SSH.

Dropping the "git:" should force dulwich to use SSH to clone.